# IE 11 shows "Page can't be displayed" on long running backend servlet processing

Tags: apache, servlets, internet-explorer-11

I have a servlet that takes more than 6 minutes to complete a operation. The application is hosted on weblogic 12c that is accessed via BIGIP F5 load balancer and then a apache server. Apache uses wl_proxy to communicate with weblogic. Whenever this servlet is called IE shows "This page can't be displayed". I turned on the wl_proxy log on apache server and found the following:

```
Exception type [READ_TIMEOUT] (no read after 300 seconds) raised at line 212 of ../nsapi/Reader.cpp
```

So I added the WLIOTimeout directive in wl_proxy.conf that fixed the one part of the problem. Still it shows the same error exactly after 5 minutes, and this time I saw the following error in wl_proxy log:

```
Fri Jul 31 12:49:05 2015 <396114383469453> created a new connection to preferred server 'xxx.x.xxx.xxx/5096' for '/getUserActivitiesReport.do?action=GENERATEREPORT', Local port:36249
Fri Jul 31 12:55:02 2015 <396114383469453> URL::parseHeaders: CompleteStatusLine set to [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Fri Jul 31 12:55:02 2015 <396114383469453> URL::parseHeaders: StatusLine set to [200 OK]
Fri Jul 31 12:55:02 2015 <396114383469453> parsed all headers OK
Fri Jul 31 12:55:02 2015 <396114383469453> sendResponse() : r->status = '200'
Fri Jul 31 12:55:02 2015 <396114383469453> Write to the browser failed: calling URL::close at line 680 of ap_proxy.cpp
Fri Jul 31 12:55:02 2015 <396114383469453> *******Exception type [WRITE_ERROR_TO_CLIENT] raised at line 681 of ap_proxy.cpp
Fri Jul 31 12:55:02 2015 <396114383469453> *NOT* failing over after sendResponse() exception: WRITE_ERROR_TO_CLIENT
Fri Jul 31 12:55:02 2015 <396114383469453> request [/getUserActivitiesReport.do?action=GENERATEREPORT] did NOT process successfully..................
```

Aapache access log for this request:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [31/Jul/2015:12:49:05 +0000] "POST /getUserActivitiesReport.do?action=GENERATEREPORT HTTP/1.1" 200 10 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" "PsHK9qECrbkAAA95AFgAAAAG" 80 357322233
```

Now why the browser closed the connection! AFAIK the IE 11 times out after 60 minutes. Also in the IE developer I saw the connection as "Aborted".
Could any one faced this types of issue. Any idea if there is any timeout set at F5 level?
Thanks in advance,
Debojit

Comment: I directly hit the weblogic server bypassing the f5 and apache; the took 17 minutes for instance, but the request ultimately succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, the solution is add this two parameters in the Weblogic plug-in configuration:

```
WLIOTimeoutSecs 14400
WLSocketTimeoutSecs 14400
```

Be careful with the parameters (14400), this are only examples.
And restart your http server.

My configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
  <Location />
    WebLogicHost 172.x.x.x
    WebLogicPort 7003
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WLIOTimeoutSecs 14400
    WLSocketTimeoutSecs 14400
  </Location>
  </IfModule>
```

More info: Doc ID 2554989.1 and
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/webtier/develop-plugin/PLGWL.pdf